# Python Socket Implementing SSL Certificate

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ssl, openssl

I was making server/client socket.
Now I want implement SSL certificate to server so connection is encrypred.
Before someone will give me link to documentation I want say that I arledy look at that, but I  still don't know how to implement that.

server.py : https://gist.github.com/comand100vip/19376a249b31ae66f46796749e2b9771
client.py : https://gist.github.com/comand100vip/a36f220fe4c0fe0bb1090b9668a79833
I put link, because client and server combined is 250 lines and I don't want here a wall of the text.

Comment: *"I arledy look at that, but I still don't know how to implement that. ..."* - this is a very unspecific problem description. Since it is unclear what you don't understand one cannot offer help which addresses your specific problems. The  [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#socket-creation) already contains examples and it makes no sense to repeat these here if the only feedback is a unspecific *"don't understand this"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import SSL and set the context. You can implement how you wish. You can move it to the init method, for example. Then wrap the socket in the SSL context.

```
import socket, ssl


class Connector:
    HEADER = 1024
    VERSION = "0.1"
    servers_count = 0
    server_alive = True
    shutdown_event = threading.Event()
    servers = []
    FORMAT = "utf-8"
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    context.load_cert_chain('/path/to/certchain.pem', '/path/to/private.key')
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    context.check_hostname = True
    context.load_default_certs()

    def __init__(self, port, server_name):
        print("\n[SERVER] Initializing server...")
        self.s = None
        self.HOST = ""  # socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        self.PORT = port
        self.server_name = server_name
        self.conn = None
        self.address = None
        self.server_infos = {f"{Connector.servers_count}": f"{self.server_name}", "PORT": f"{self.PORT}", "HOST":
                         f"{self.HOST}"}
        Connector.servers.append(self.server_infos)
        print(f'[SERVER] Created server: "{self.server_name}", index of server: {self.servers_count}')
        Connector.servers_count += 1

 def create_socket(self):
    print(f"[{self.server_name} - INFO] Creating socket...")
    try:
        self.s = socket.socket()
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(self.s,server_hostname=self.HOST)
        ssl_sock.connect((self.address, self.PORT))
        print(f"[{self.server_name} - DONE] Creating socket done!")
    except socket.error as error_msg:
        print(f"[{self.server_name} - ERROR] creating socket:\n{error_msg}")
```

Comment: How can I specify path to my SSL Certificate?
Does client need any changes?

Comment: Here is the docs.. see updated answer as I missed adding this part! Should be load_cert_chain() method https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html

Comment: Im not totally sure how your process works but you may need to wrap your client socket too

Comment: But how do I wrap client socket? I thnk it only like need certificate on the server side. like every website.

Comment: This doesn't look like an SSL server. Where do you call `accept()` on the listening socket?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  Line [99](https://gist.github.com/comand100vip/19376a249b31ae66f46796749e2b9771#file-server-py-L99)

Comment: @noone_interesting in the create socket method, the wrap_socket method is wrapping it.